# Error while setting up a multi-broker cluster on Local Machine

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-cluster

Using Kafka on Ubuntu:
Zookeeper started
Kafka started
Topic Created
Producer started
Consumer started
Messages are delivering fine from producer to consumer

I created 2 new server.properties files as:
server-1.properties as:

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
log.dir=C:\kafka\kafka-logs-1
```

server-2.properties as:

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094
log.dir=C:\kafka\kafka-logs-2
```

When i started the new broker as:

```
bin\windows\kafka-server-start.sh config\server-1.properties &
```

Got Error as:

```
kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:9092: Address already in use: bind
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the brokers you've added, are both listening to port `9092` which is currently in use by the first broker.

In `server-1.properties` file you need to add

```
port=9093
```

and in `server-2.properties`

```
port=9094
```

Keep these lines `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093`, `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094` commented out.

Also make sure you use different `broker.id` for every instance.

If you are trying to setup a Multi-broker Kafka Cluster with a single Zookeeper node, you might find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SspgvvQ13DU) useful.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using multiple brokers then use the following type of broker declaration on the

server.properties

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
```

server.1.properties

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs1
```

server.2.properties

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs2
```

server.3.properties

```
broker.id=3
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9095
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my local setup with 3 different vms running kafka and 1 zookeeper, 2 were starting fine except one. I was referred to check the /etc/hosts which had wrong ip set to the name, after fixing that my 3 brokers started without any issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are running confluent version, make sure to update the following

first broker:
`confluent.metadata.server.listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8090`

second broker:
`confluent.metadata.server.listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8091`